# Sencha Touch 2: How to create global inline xtemplate config method?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

In the ideal world in my mind I would have this on my `Ext.dataview.List`:

```
itemTpl: '{name:customFunction}'
```

where customFunction is then global/static function I can reuse on all templates. What is the closest real world solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest is to do like you say... Just add your custom function to `Ext.util.Format`.

Example:

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.util.Format'

    ,customFunction: function(value, append) {
        return 'This is it: ' 
            + value
            + (Ext.isDefined(append) ? append : ''); // you can use args too
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I've made it `Ext.define('Tm.ux.Format', {` though; and it works like a charm

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your best bet:

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '{[this.getGlobalValue()]}',
    {
        getGlobalValue: MyApp.util.Utils.globalTplFunction
    }
)
```

Then, in your Utils file:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.Utils', {
    singleton: true,
    globalTplFunction: function() {
        //do whatever here
        return "Result!";
    }
});
```